# Increment Date on file name using Batch code

Tags: batch-file, cmd, increment, ddos

Hi basically I have this text file with the name "Report 08/11/2015",

I would like to create a batch file which when clicked would set the current date, or at least increment the numbers.

**Any idea how I could do this?**

Comment: Set the current date to where? How much do you want to increment?

Comment: To _"set the current date"_ use `date` command. To _"increment the numbers"_ use `set /A numbers+=1`. If you want a more precise answer, please post a more precise question!

Comment: managed to do it answer is below, thanks :)

Comment: @NigelPace you absolutely do not have a file named with slashes in it. That is an illegal character in a filename in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it, sorry if my question wasn't so clear but this basically changes the text file name to the current date

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

ren "C:\Users\np\Desktop\text.txt" "Report - %fullstamp%.txt"
```